# What is UEFI's boot sequence?

Tags: uefi

I tried to find answer to this question in Internet, but got no luck.
Also, while analyzing source codes of "edk2" folder (TianoCore), I couldn't find the answer.

P.S. I understand, that Intel provides a lot of documentation, but it is difficult to find generalized information about boot flow in thousands of documentation's pages. That's why I'm asking for help from the community!

Comment: That's a *very* broad question. If you can narrow it down some, I'll try to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [UEFI Specification](http://www.uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Spec_2_7.pdf) (see **3 Boot Manager** for more information) states:

> The boot sequence for UEFI consists of the following:
>
> • The boot order list is read from a globally defined NVRAM variable. Modifications to this variable are only guaranteed to take effect after the next platform reset. The boot order list defines a list of NVRAM variables that contain information about what is to be booted. Each NVRAM variable defines a name for the boot option that can be displayed to a user.
>
> • The variable also contains a pointer to the hardware device and to a file on that hardware device that contains the UEFI image to be loaded.
>
> • The variable might also contain paths to the OS partition and directory along with other configuration specific directories

If this is what you're asking.

Comment: thank you for your reply! Your answer is right, but due to the incorrect formulation of my question I cannot get the answer required. Anyway, thanks! I am accepting the answer and it is probably better way to create new question which explains what I really need.